# Roxy Fileman - Image Dimensions not updated after edit

Tags: uploader, roxy-fileman

Below are the steps I am doing:

-If we upload an image picture.jpg with dimensions 100x100

-Delete it from Roxy Fileman

-Changing the dimensions of picture.jpg to 200x200 and re-uploading it with Roxy Fileman,

-If we preview it it shows the old dimensions `100x100` instead of `200x200`

**Note** that we upload form the same directory and the file with the same name and extension, and if we change the picture to another picture with the same name it shows the wrong preview.

Could it be fixed to show the right dimensions 200x200 and right preview?